# Is Magi based on religion?

Tags: magi

I started reading the manga Magi recently and can't help but get the feeling that it is based on Islam.

I couldn't find anything online, and neither do I have enough knowledge about the religion to really confirm this either.

So is the story of Magi based on Islam? Or does it use certain key points from this religion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Precaution: The following may contain spoilers from Magi

This was too long to be posted in comments so I had to make it here and since it serves the purpose too, why not.

So I did a bit of research after the few pointers given out by Dimitri.

On the reference manga page given by Dimitri, I found this:

[image: magi-chapter219-page18]

After looking up the two names **David** and **Solomon**, I found the interesting:

> Solomōn), also called Jedidiah (Hebrew יְדִידְיָהּ), was, according to
>   the Book of Kings, the Book of Chronicles, Hidden Words and the
>   Qur'an[2] a king of Israel and the son of **David**. <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxtB2.png)</sup>

Book of Chronicles are the final books of the Hebrew Bible.

When you search about Solomon in Islam, the first line you see in wikipedia:

> **Solomon** (Arabic سليمان Sulaymān) was, according to the Qur'an, a king
>   of ancient Israel as well as the son of **David**. <sup>2</sup>

Solomon in Islam is more usually called as *Sulaymān* and David as *Daud or Dawud*.

The name **Jehoahaz** also seems to have a reference in the [Bible](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=II%20Kings%2023:31-25:30), but not the Quran. So judging from the names used in the anime, they might be relating it more to Christianity.

More information about the names [here](http://magi.wikia.com/wiki/David_Jehoahaz_Abraham#Trivia)

And about the **Ilah**:

ʾIlāh (Arabic: إله‎; plural: آلهة ʾālihah) is an Arabic term meaning "deity". , it simply means **deity** in Arabic. So you might be confusing it with Allah who is the God of Muslims.

Summing it up, we can say that Solomon's identity and his Father, David's identity has been taken from religion (more like Christianity) but most part of Magi is derived from fictional characters.

---

#### References

<sup>1</sup> [Solomon reference from Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon)

<sup>2</sup> [Solomon reference from Quran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_in_Islam)

Comment: So in the end it pretty much comes down to religious key points being used, but the series has not specifically been based on religion?

Comment: @Dimitrimx Exactly! My reasoning -> Probably because of the fact that it has more impact on the story-line when based on real-life/historic events but too much of it may offend some community.

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is no. It is not based on the Islamic religion. It is based on a several middle eastern originating stories and historical characters.

The main characters names such as Ali Baba and Cassim are from [1001 Nights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Thousand_and_One_Nights) also known as the Arabian nights. [Sinbad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinbad) is also a character from a series of arabian stories. Solomon was a real king back in 970BC.

Basically what they have done is pulled in several popular names from Arab stories and literature and Middle Eastern history and mixed it in with their story. I'm too new to link more references, but you get the idea.

Comment: That covers the name parts. But in some of the more recent chapters where aladin shows solomons wisdom to the people we see them talking about Illah sons of i believe it was abraham . And offcourse the book (forgot the name) which they regard as soeme holy book. Those specific events and names made me think it might be religion related. As i have a small background in religion

Comment: They draw from several stories, including tales from the Qu'ran but like I said, they are simply taking familiar names and situations and fitting them into the world of Magi. It's similar to how the new Noah movie is. It has Noah, the arc and the animals, but it's in its own style with new characters and events that are not canon.

Comment: @Dimitrimx Since it's an anime partly portraying arab culture, it won't be odd for them to use arabic words too. I haven't read the Magi manga, but have they mentioned 'Abraham' anywhere? I think likely not. Also, Abraham comes from the Bible, Ibrahim is from Quran.

Comment: @user007 chapter 219 page 18 jehoahaz abraham and david jehoahaz abraham, here is also mentioned that he is the  first senator in the orthodox counil of elders. Looking back I see some Key points from both relgions coming back in there.

Comment: I think we should say it is not based on a single religion, but it definitely uses religion mixed with magic as a fundamental element.

Answer (score 2):

I am Muslim and my answer is, no it's not based on Islam. The culture in Magi was based on the Middle East before Islam.

Jenn, magic, and harem were very common at that time and thousand of stories talked about jennies talking and serve people, and some people were practicing real magic.

There are some events that have been taken from Qur'an as Solomon story and how Allah gave him the power to control jennies and animals.

Answer (score 0):

Magi take place in the Middle East before Islam when the Middle Eastern countries were either Christian countries or countries of Judaism.

I'm guessing *Magi* takes place in Iraq which used to be a Christian country.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, Sinbad was a real Muslim explorer
- Pricess Dunya: Dunya is the Arabic word for "worldliness"
- Solomon and David are the main prophets in Islam, Christianity, and Judaism
- Jinn are found in the Islam's Qur'an
- Even Satan is a jinn in the Qur'an
- Some say the three wise men of the bible were three Muslim (magi) scholars
- They all take a pilgrimage during their adventures
- A pillar and requirement in Islam if one can afford the trip

Answer (score -1):

*Magi* takes place in Iraq.

Balbadd is based on Baghdad, if it wasn't obvious enough. Sinbad, Morgiana, Alibaba, and Aladdin are all from Iraq according to the Arabian Nights story. Also, the architecture is just like Iraq and what the background characters wear are based on traditional Iraqi clothes.

Comment: You need to source this information.